# skip parsing statements if "if" condition fails

Tags: parsing, bison

I am trying to create a simple parser.

```
cond:   T_IF '(' exp ')' '#' stmt_block opt_elseifs opt_else end    {if($3 == 0) return;}

opt_elseifs : /* Nothing */                                                        
            | opt_elseifs  T_ELSIF '(' exp ')' '#' stmt_block '#'                  
;
opt_else : /* Nothing */
         | T_ELSE '#' stmt_block '#'
;
end : '#'
;
```

For Example,

```
a = 0;
if(a) #
c = 10 + 20;
#
```

I don't want value of c printed,but this is printing value of c.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you put `'#'` instead of `end` in your `cond` rule?

Comment: thank you Basile..but i guess that's not the real problem here

Comment: I don't understand the question. How is `c` printed??? What is your lexer?? Who is printing `c` ???

Answer (score 0):

Found solution after reading bison manual.So,I thought I better also share it here.
I should be doing

```
cond:   T_IF '(' exp ')'     { if($3 == 0) return; }
        '#' stmt_block  opt_elseifs opt_else end    
;
```

So,if the exp is evaluated to be false,it does not parse any further.

Comment: This seems very wrong: `return` will return from `yyparse`, and you should never do that, or use `YYABORT`/`YYACCEPT`.